# Machine learning classifier that allows interpretation of which features contributed to a prediction

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am working on a loan prediction dataset which already has multiple features and output label `Rejected`. In the dataset, some of the input variables are continuous and some are categorical.

I would to like to know the machine learning model which can provide the reason behind the rejection of the loan. Is there a machine learning model which can be implemented to get the output in the form of the reason behind the rejection, e.g. due to a particular feature, such as a missing field, or credit history, income, marital status, etc.?

I am new to this field and open to any suggestions.

Comment: Tree models are the closest thing you are going to get to this.  They will be able to explicitly show which combinations of variables lead to which decision.  You will not, however, be able to understand *why* divorced couples are rejected from loans, for example.

Comment: Check out SHAP values for XGBoost.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I looked into SHAP. Will it tell different SHAP values for whole dataset or only 1 SHAP value for each row in dataset?